# How to avoid null insertion in ArrayList?

Tags: java

How to avoid null insertion in ArrayList while inserting element?

```
ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
al.add(null);//should avoid
.
.
.
al.add("Ramesh");
```

Comment: By not writing `al.add(null)`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: If this is happening in a loop and an element might be null, have an if-check inside to make sure the element is not null before inserting into the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

Avoiding `null` can be harmful sometimes and it could hide possible bugs.

If you're worried about getting `NullPointerException` in some stage, you can simply check if the item stored in the `ArrayList` is `null`.

You cannot disallow inserting `null` to `ArrayList`.

Comment: Exactly. seems OP  overlooking at his problem.

Comment: Can you please give example bugs by avoiding null?

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran Suppose you're inserting Strings after you perform some operation on it to the `ArrayList`. Now suppose that at some point, you failed to perform something on a String and as a result you return `null`. If you don't insert it, you might think that all Strings were fine..

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own ArrayList-Class (derived from the original) and override the Add-Method
Then you could check for null when Adding.

```
@Override
public boolean add(E e) {
  if (e == null) return false;
  else return super.add(e)
}
```

As Mark stated in the comments you perhaps want to override all other possibilties of Adding values too. ([see the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html))

- add(E e)
- add(int index, E element)
- addAll(Collection c)
- addAll(int index, Collection c)
- set(int index, E element)

Comment: That's a half-baked solution. What about `addAll` and all other ways to mutate the list?

Comment: There's also the `listIterator` and its `add` and `set` methods... this is certainly way above beginner level, and this is a beginner question.

Comment: how about `public void add(int index, E element)`??

Comment: Hey, i have add(int index, E element).
But you're right - perhaps this is not the best way, especially if you're a java-beginner ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that, But if you want to do exactly what you are trying you have to rewrite `add()` in `ArrayList` class. Using this validation you can avoid `null`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
    al=add(al,null);
    al=add(al,"Ramesh");
    al=add(al,"hi");
}

public static ArrayList<String> add(ArrayList<String> al,String str){
   if(str!=null){
      al.add(str);
      return al;
   }else {
      return al;
   }
}
```

In this case you have to call your custom `add` method to add element

Comment: Extends class is more sexy for me.. Anyway you don't need to return the instance of the arraylist. Or at least use al = add () everytime. Just add (al, ..)

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>() {

            @Override
            public boolean add(String s ) {

                if( s != null ) {
                    return super.add( s );
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
al.add(null);
al.add("blabla");
```